# Uncaught Syantax error | Mailchimp API

Tags: jsonp, mailchimp

I am using MailChimp API with JSONP but it gives me error. How can i slove it.

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "//us13.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/lists/subscribe.json?apikey=XXX&id=0e1e74bfd0&email[email]=citstestdev@gmail.com&double_optin=false&send_welcome=false",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: "c", // trigger MailChimp to return a JSONP response
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            jsonpCallback: "myJsonMethod",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What error does it give ?

Comment: Error - 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: jQuery can not catch AJAX response. Google Chrome gives me - "uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token"

Comment: Error Screenshot - http://awesomescreenshot.com/0f1677vwaa

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome gives me - "uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token"

Because `console,log(data);` should be `console.log(data);`. (dot instead of comma)

Also, you can fetch errors doing a jQuery.ajax chain with done & fail, as so:

```
$.ajax({
    // ... ajax options
}).done(function (result) {
    console.log(result) // everything's ok
}).fail(function (error) {
    console.error(error) // something went wrong
})
```

Comment: You should change your code to the done/fail chain as the error ajax option will not be triggered in case of error as stated here: `This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests` [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: `Recipient <email> has too many recent signup requests.` means that they temporary "blacklisted" the email to be signed up against I suppose a mailing list ? You can still try a different email...

Comment: But its give me - "500 Internal Server Error" ? that's why jQuery ajax can not catch the response. I need to show the result to end user. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can catch the error using the done/fail chain as I answered, and in the fail you will have `error.error` which is the message which MailChimp returns you (;